# Use Perl to edit HTML files

Tags: html, perl

The output below is generated by a third party tool which validates XML files against a XML Schema. It will output validation errors. Ok, so that was just a little context.

From the errors above are displayed in HTML, I want to be able to perform "syntax highlighting" using perl. For instance, I want to be able to highlight certain parts of the text above.

Specifically, I want to colour any text that conforms to "Line [0-9]*" as bold and in red. I've tried to experiment with regex search and replace but I've not been that successful.

Any pointers/hints would be fantastic.

Thank you!

```
Line 8: Element 'alphabet', attribute 'letters': The value 'XYZ' does not match the fixed value constraint 'ABC'.
Line 185: Element 'drink': The attribute 'coffee' is required but missing.
Line 254: Element 'timeout': This element is not expected.
Line 269: Element 'commands': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( eat, drink, sleep ).
Line 812: Element 'software': The attribute 'version' is required but missing.
Line 876: Element 'windows-software': The attribute 'version' is required but missing.
Line 890: Element 'contact': The attribute 'telephone' is required but missing.
Line 890: Element 'operating': The attribute 'mode' is required but missing.
```

Comment: You should probably show the regex, and some of the HTML code you want to highlight

Comment: The text above is what is displayed in a HTML file. That is what I would want to perform highlighting on

Comment: You do realize there is no HTML in there, right? Is the text in a `pre` block?

Comment: There doesn't need to be any HTML above. This is a question about text, whether it be displayed in a HTML file or notepad. I want to be able to add HTML to the text.

Comment: The title of the question is *Use Perl to edit HTML files*

Answer (score 1):

Have a try with this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;

while(<DATA>) {
    s#(Line \d+)#<span style="font-weight:bold;color:red;">$1</span>#;
    s#(Element\s|attribute\s)('[^']*')#$1<span style="font-weight:bold;color:blue;">$2</span>#g;
    print
}

__DATA__
Line 8: Element 'alphabet', attribute 'letters': The value 'XYZ' does not match the fixed value constraint 'ABC'.
Line 185: Element 'drink': The attribute 'coffee' is required but missing.
Line 254: Element 'timeout': This element is not expected.
```

**output**

```
<span style="font-weight:bold;color:red;">Line 8</span>: Element <span style="font-weight:bold;color:blue;">'alphabet'</span>, attribute <span style="font-weight:bold;color:blue;">'letters'</span>: The value 'XYZ' does not match the fixed value constraint 'ABC'.
<span style="font-weight:bold;color:red;">Line 185</span>: Element <span style="font-weight:bold;color:blue;">'drink'</span>: The attribute <span style="font-weight:bold;color:blue;">'coffee'</span> is required but missing.
<span style="font-weight:bold;color:red;">Line 254</span>: Element <span style="font-weight:bold;color:blue;">'timeout'</span>: This element is not expected.
```

Instead of style attribut, you can use a css class.

```
s#(Line \d+)#<span class="bold_red">$1</span>#;
```

Comment: So I tried to perform highlighting for the text after the word "Element" but it seems to high more than I need.
I want to be able to higtlight the word immediately after "Element" and "attribute". The command below seems to hight "Element: 'aplhabet' whereas I only want 'alphabet' highlighted

$output =~ s#(Element(\s)['](\w)*(-)*(\w)*['])#<span style="font-weight:bold;color:blue;">$1</span>#g;